# C# Httpwebrequest Useragent

Tags: c#

I wrote a scrip to get the Google Search top Urls. One biggest issue for this script is that, it is return the search result based upon my IP. That is to say,say, i am in Chicago, it is returning the results from location Chicago instead of US. I figure that can have something to do with the useragent:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

   request.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml,         image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";

   request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US";
   request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";

   request.KeepAlive = true;
   request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
   request.Timeout = 60000;

   request.Method = "GET";
```

Does anyone have ideas about why i am getting the search for local?

Comment: I seriously doubt it could be because of the user agent. You might want to check the API and the parameters passed to it. It might be taking your current location based on IP because some location or area parameter is missing.

Comment: Are you using an API, or are you screen-scraping?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the User Agent, Google usually pin point your location by IP, so that's why if you're in Chicago, you get results from Chicago, if you go through a proxy you will get results based on the estimated location of the IP of that proxy.

Answer (score 1):

As http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179386 states, you can override the automatic location detection by specifying one directly in the search query.

> If you'd like to see results for a region outside of your Google
>   domain, please specify the location in the search query, like [
>   bicycle repair paris ] or visit a different Google local domain
>   instead.